# dart analyzer error: argument_type_not_assignable

Tags: dart, analyzer

```dart
TrackPoint tp
Type: TrackPoint

The argument type 'TrackPoint
(where TrackPoint is defined in ...lib\\trackpoint.dart)'
can't be assigned to
the parameter type 'TrackPoint (where TrackPoint is defined in ...lib\\trackPoint.dart)'.dart
**(argument_type_not_assignable)**
trackpoint.dart(8, 7): TrackPoint is defined in ...lib\\trackpoint.dart
trackPoint.dart(8, 7): TrackPoint is defined in ...lib\\trackPoint.dart
```

Here is where the error is:

```dart
import 'trackpoint.dart' show TrackPoint;

class TrackingStatus {
  // ...
  static void _triggerEvent(TrackPoint tp) {
  // ...
  TrackingStatusChangedEvent.trigger(tp); // <-- error on tp, see above
}
```

Here is what causes the error:

```dart
class TrackingStatusChangedEvent {
  static void trigger(TrackPoint tp) { // <-- causes error
    // ...
  }

  static void trigger(tp) { // <-- works but tp should not be dynamic
    // ...
  }
}
```

Here is where TrackPoint comes from:

```dart
class TrackPoint {
  static final List<TrackPoint> _trackPoints = [];

  void _addTrackPoint() {
    _trackPoints.add(this);
  }
```

argument_type_not_assignable is not reasonable for me. Especially because the error message points to the same class in the same file as if they are something different

Comment: This is the error I get on runtime leaving tp dynamic:type 'TrackPoint' is not a subtype of type 'TrackPoint' where
  TrackPoint is from package:chaostours/trackPoint.dart
  TrackPoint is from package:chaostours/trackpoint.dart

Answer (score 0):

I recommend just using **prefixes** for library import. See below.

```
import 'trackpoint.dart' as tp;
```

Then use it like this.

```
class TrackPoint {
  static final List<tp.TrackPoint> _trackPoints = [];



void _addTrackPoint() {
    _trackPoints.add(this);
```

Comment: Looks like the problem comes from trackPoint.dart imports trackingStatus.dart - vice versa. Because putting both classes in the same file sovled the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Putting class TrackPoint and class TrackingStatus the same file solved the problem. May be it was a cross loading issue.

Thanks for your help anyway!